# Create a datetime.time object just from seconds

Tags: python, datetime

I need to convert to convert an integer into a datetime.time instance. I get the time in elapsed seconds so it may well be larger than 59.

I know that I can create a time object by using:

```
import datetime
def to_time(seconds):
    hours = seconds / 3600
    mins = (seconds%3600)/60
    sec = (seconds%3600)%60
    return datetime.time(hours,mins,sec)
```

and I could hand this over to a mapping function if a have list of timevalues to convert. But I think it is ugly. Isn't there a better way to do so?

Actually, the problem is a bit more complex. I get a floating point as time where `datetime.date.fromordinal(int(time))` returns the date and `to_time(time - int(time)*86400)` would return the time. I can than combine them to my datetime-object. So the input would be for example 734869.00138889, which should result in 2013-01-01 00:02

I would definitely prefer a less crowded method.

Comment: Can you give us an actual value for `time`?

Comment: edited question accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: is this floating point value coming from a spreadsheet?

Comment: Nope, a colleague of mine considered this a good idea and stored it (using python!) in hdf5. I tend to differ. But yes, I think this is the Excel-Approach... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to use a `datetime.timedelta()` object with your `time` value as the `days` argument, and add that to `datetime.datetime.min`; that'll be off by one day so you have to subtract 1 from the value:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt = datetime.min + timedelta(days=time - 1)
```

This avoids having to cast the value to an integer for the ordinal, then just the fraction for the time portion.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> t = 734869.00138889
>>> datetime.min + timedelta(days=t - 1)
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 93)
```

Comment: In this case `days=` is optional.

Comment: @PauloScardine: explicit is better than implicit; this way you don't have to look up what the default parameter was again.

Comment: Well, this is a much nicer solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood how to convert the number after the decimal point to seconds, but I would try something along this line:

```
def to_datetime(time):
    return datetime.datetime.fromordinal(int(time)) + \
           datetime.timedelta(time % 1)
```

[update]

Is this the result you want?

```
>>> to_datetime(734869.00138889)
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 93)
```

Comment: You can use `days=time % 1` perhaps.

Comment: You'll also need to use `datetime.datetime()` if you want to add a `timedelta()` and have it work.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for me - the first object is of type datetime.date and doesn't care about a timedelta < 1 day :( **EDIT: WORKS!** with datetime.datetime it works, wasn't aware that fromordinal is also available for datetime... .

Comment: It is impossible to beat Martijn on the Python tag. :-)

Comment: Yes, I'm only around for a few days, but I already realized he is unbelievable fast and competent. This was the result I expected. Thanks!